# How to add the analytics experiment code in the Homepage WordPress PHP header?

Tags: php, wordpress, analytics

I add the following to my header.php of WordPress theme

```
 <?php if(is_front_page()){ ?>
----google analytics experiment code---
 <?php } ?>
```

But doesn't work, do you have any suggestion?

Thank

Comment: well, it would be a good idea to add a little more code and details to your problem.

Comment: Yes just add it, sorry it didn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject this code higher into your WordPress header using a WordPress hook with a high priority in your themes functions.php file. Google Experiment Code

```
function google_experiment_code() {
    ?>
    // Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->

    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head','google_experiment_code', 5 );
```

Finally the action wp_head will run this function with a `priority of 5`. you could run it even higher by using a lower number.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the info.  but I'm trying to add the google experiment code. which is different than standard analytics. It goes into the header of the homepage. But i did that already 4 days ago but nothing happened :(

Comment: Then you need to add the code to the higher priority in your wordpress, check my updated answer..

Comment: Thanks i will try, i just add the above function to my functions.php into the chid theme right? (i am using a child theme) . Thank you

Comment: Yes ofcourse it will work in child themes too, After adding the code in your wordpress function.php and make sure none of your seo plugins are blocking it.. It usually takes upto 12-24 hours to work!

Comment: Hello, ok thanks for the feedback.But How should i find out if a set plug in block it? Thanks

Comment: In my answer i have set the priority of 5, you can change it to like 2,3 if it doesnot work at 5 because maybe some seo plugins like yoast etc have higher priority.. but make sure important SEO tags are kept first in the priority order.

Comment: Thank you, i will try! But how do you check the priority which the other plugins have?

Comment: it works, i increased the number to 3 but how do you know the priority the other plug in have?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i was out of town, Basically we don't know which plugin has the highest priority set, We use many different plugins, everyone has its own priority. that's why WordPress has allowed us to set the priority to our choice for any plugin.. @nic

Comment: thank you!! one last thing, do you know why i notice on analytics that all the traffic is going to the experiment page? i mean not all but 90% ish even if i set 50% traffic to each page? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a PHP if-else statement based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to match the home page. Code you posted is working for me.

OR try `is_home()` is WordPress version old ?

Comment: hello, the version is new. Now I'm trying as above mentioned from Sapio, but lets see if it works! thanks